# Warning: Find more than one child node with `children` in ResizeObserver. Will only observe first one

Tags: reactjs, react-resize-observer

Like the description of title.In my react application has the Warning.

System: Mac OS Big Sur 11.2

Enviroment: Chrome 89.0.4389.90（正式版本） (x86_64)

[image: The warning detail]

Comment: Can you add the code that's actually causing the error? Just sounds like that resize observer component expects to have only ONE direct child element, but you have multiple: https://github.com/react-component/resize-observer/blob/master/src/index.tsx#L143

Comment: that's why i can't solve problem. The page's code is too much to display on. I do not know where the code cause.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect this is the same problem I had with Ant Design `<Affix />` Component.

Basically, your Affix Component (probably) has multiple children as below:

```
<Affix>
    <div>...1</div>
    <div>...2</div>
</Affix>
```

It should only have one child - a little like React JSX should only have one root component returned.

So the above can become:

```
<Affix>
    <div>
        <div>...1</div>
        <div>...2</div>
    </div>
</Affix>
```